# Having trouble loading a ruby file from desktop to irb

Tags: ruby, terminal, irb

I am working on a small app in Ruby.  The file is called "cookbook.rb" and it is saved on my Mac desktop.

At first I type

```
cd desktop
```

which takes me into desktop, and then I try and load the file so that I can check it out in irb.  I type this:

```
load 'cookbook.rb'
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: cookbook.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
from (irb):1:in `load'
from (irb):1
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I followed the same directions that I used to create and work on another .rb file, and it worked just fine before.

Sorry for the confusion...here is the file cookbook.rb

```
 Cookbook = Class.new

 Recipe = Class.new

 Class Cookbook
     def initialize(title)
         @title = title
     end
 end

Class Recipe
    def initialize(title, ingredients, steps)
        @title = title
        @ingredients = ingredients
        @steps = steps
    end
end
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with Mac, your directory, terminal, or irb. You need to show the content of `cookbook.rb`.

Comment: The error is in the `cookbook.rb` file

Comment: sawa....forgive me if my question is silly.  I am not sure what you mean exactly...like I mentioned above, it worked before and I am not sure if I "showed" content when it worked on previous occasions

Comment: so there is an error in my file?

Comment: What I meant by "show" is that you should write it in this question here.

Comment: `Class Cookbook` and `Class Recipe` are invalid. There is no method `Class`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Class` to `class`, i.e., the keyword `class` should be written in lower case.

```
class Cookbook
    def initialize(title)
        @title = title
    end
end

class Recipe
    def initialize(title, ingredients, steps)
        @title = title
        @ingredients = ingredients
        @steps = steps
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks buddy...very much appreceiated